# Show output on screen and in file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I get all this to not only output on the screen, but to save to a text file in [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format?

```
$OUs = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)" `
     -SearchBase "OU=GA,OU=EAST,DC=corp,DC=chm,DC=com" | Select distinguishedName
 ForEach ($OU In $OUs)
 {
     $OU.distinguishedName
     Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU.distinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel `
         -Filter * | Select Name
 }
```

I have tried

```
$OUs = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)" `
     -SearchBase "OU=GA,OU=EAST,DC=corp,DC=chartercom,DC=com" | Select distinguishedName
 ForEach ($OU In $OUs)
 {
     $OU.distinguishedName
     Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU.distinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel `
         -Filter * | Select Name
 } | | export-CSV c:\temp\outfile.csv –noType
```

And many other formats, but I always get the error:

> An empty pipe element is not allowed.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx) cmdlet.

> The Tee-Object cmdlet enables you to display data in the Windows PowerShell window and to save that same data to a text file, all with a single command.

```
dir | Tee-Object -file dir.txt
```

You should use it like,

```
 ForEach ($OU In $OUs)
 {
     $OU.distinguishedName
     Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU.distinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel `
         -Filter * | Select Name
 } | Tee-Object -file c:\temp\outfile.txt
```

**Note:** It has an alias, `tee`, which is the same as Unix' [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29).

Comment: $OUs = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)" `
     -SearchBase "OU=GA,OU=EAST,DC=corp,DC=chm,DC=com" | Select distinguishedName
 ForEach ($OU In $OUs)
 {
     $OU.distinguishedName
     Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU.distinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel `
         -Filter * | Select Name 
 }  Tee-Object -file c:\temp\outfile.txt

Comment: I am and i am getting the same error              }| Tee-Object -file c:\temp\outfile.txt




An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:8 char:3

Comment: i got it to work with Tee but i had to (and i will try to use the right terms) wrap that in { } and maike it a function.  I was then able to Tee the function.    Thanks

Comment: `Tee-Object` has not exactly the most meaningful name Microsoft could've given the cmdlet. But then, it is Powershell..

Comment: Unfortunately `Tee-Object` does not have an `-Encoding` option so it always outputs in UTF-16, which many tools don't support properly.

Comment: `Tee-Object` does not grab all output, you need to capture every stream with `*>&1` and then pipe it to tee, example: `... *>&1 | Tee-Object ...`

Comment: @MarkusL This is true for any command after `|`. This is the feature of the command interpreter. In this case, powershell.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select Name, Version | Sort Name | Tee-Object -file h:\InstalledApps.TXT
```

Comment: How do we append to file instead of overwrite it? Use the `-Append` parameter of `Tee-Object`

Answer (score 1):

> An empty pipe element is not allowed.

You have a duplicate bar in the last line:

```
} | | export-CSV c:\temp\outfile.csv –noType
```

That doesn't fix the error completely, because you can't pipe directly from the foreach loop. You can export it another way to a CSV file instead of a text file like Tee-Object does (you could convert Tee-Object to CSV). This way, it outputs the results to a CSV file and prints the results to the screen:

```
$OUs = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)" `
         -SearchBase "OU=GA,OU=EAST,DC=corp,DC=chartercom,DC=com" | Select distinguishedName

$results = @()
ForEach ($OU In $OUs)
{
    $OU.distinguishedName
    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $OU.distinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel `
                   -Filter * | Select Name
} $results | Export-Csv c:\temp\outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
write-host $results
```

This can also be done with a much simpler script:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=GA,OU=EAST,DC=corp,DC=chartercom,DC=com" -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * | Select Name | Export-Csv c:\temp\outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv c:\temp\outfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

tee-object is nice but very limited. for those who need more control over the function - use write-log function from eNLib

install-module eNLib

write-log enables to fork text, objects, define logfile with start-logging function, doesn't require to define logfile name each time - very useful for advanced scripting.